How to remove a Kafka consumer group from a specific topic in Kafka 2.2?
I have 2 consumer groups, a & b.
group a listened to topicB.
I've made changes and now I want group a to listen to topicA and group b to listen to topicB
But I ended up with:
a --> topicA + topicB
b --> topicB
how can I remove group a from topicB?
tried running
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server  --delete-offsets
command but it's only available from version 2.4
I cannot update my Kafka unfortunately

Groups have topics, not the other way around... You should just be able to remove topicB from the subscription list of the consumer app
